# React useState and useEffect does not work as expected

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I have one state for storing an object and two useffects. The first useeffect occurs only once in the first render, while the second occurs whenever the 'toFetch' state is changed. In addition, has an initial value for toFetch that is the coordinates of Ankara and is stored in object. First, useffect determines whether the user has granted permission for geolocation. If allowed, it is set to fetch the current location; if it is not, it does nothing. This time, the second useffect works. and basically fetches data from the API and sets the "selected" state. However, when the user allows geolocation, the selected state continues to use Ankara coordinates. What is the problem?

Here is my Code

```
function Contex({ children }) {
  let obj = { lat: 39.57, lng: 32.53 }; // coordinates of ankara
  const [weather, setWeather] = useState([]);
  const [selected, setSelected] = useState({});
  const [toFetch, settoFetch] = useState(obj);
  const [loading, setloading] = useState(false);


  useEffect(() => {
    const initialSetup = () => {
      const sb = (pos) => {
        const {
          coords: { latitude, longitude },
        } = pos;


         settoFetch((prev) => {
           return { type: "single", lat: latitude, lng: longitude };
         });

      };
      const eb = (err) => {};

      navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(sb, eb, {
        enableHighAccuracy: true,
      });
    };
    initialSetup();
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    const den = async () => {
      setloading(true);
      let x = toFetch;
      if (toFetch.type === "country") x = await getCountryStates(toFetch.name);
      const weatherData = await dataProvider([x].flat());
      setWeather(weatherData);
      setSelected(weatherData[0]);
      setloading(false);
    };

    den();
  }, [toFetch]);

  return (
    <context.Provider
      value={{
        weather,
        setSelected,
        selected,
        settoFetch,
        loading,
        toFetch,
      }}
    >
      {children}
    </context.Provider>
  );
}

export { Contex, context };
```

Edit 1:

I tried to use geolocation as promise but it also did not work. Please help

Answer (score 1):

```
function Contex({ children }) {
  let obj = { lat: 39.57, lng: 32.53 }; // coordinates of ankara
  const [weather, setWeather] = useState([]);
  const [selected, setSelected] = useState({});
  const [toFetch, settoFetch] = useState(obj);
  const [loading, setloading] = useState(false);


  useEffect(() => {
    const initialSetup = () => {
      const sb = (pos) => {
        const {
          coords: { latitude, longitude },
        } = pos;


         settoFetch((prev) => {
           return { type: "single", lat: latitude, lng: longitude };
         });

      };
      const eb = (err) => {};

      navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(sb, eb, {
        enableHighAccuracy: true,
      });
    };
    initialSetup();
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    const den = async () => {
      setloading(true);
      let x = toFetch;
      if (toFetch.type === "country") x = await getCountryStates(toFetch.name);
      const weatherData = await dataProvider([x].flat());
      setWeather(weatherData);
      setSelected(weatherData[0]);
      setloading(false);
    };

    den();
  }, [toFetch.lat, toFetch.lng]); // Using an object in your useEffect dependency array also causes the infinite loop problem.

  return (
    <context.Provider
      value={{
        weather,
        setSelected,
        selected,
        settoFetch,
        loading,
        toFetch,
      }}
    >
      {children}
    </context.Provider>
  );
}

export { Contex, context };
```

Comment: No sir. It is falling into a loop. It did not worked as you expected. Is there any solution can you offer?

Comment: I think this time it will work

Comment: I am sorry,sir. But this one does not work too. I think maybe the problem is using two useEffect. Do you think may be this be the problem?

Comment: using two useEffect is not causing the problem. 
Maybe some other reason could cause the problem